# Want to show all elements at once in plot, but this doesn't

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently I try to show result of my Random Number Generator on plot, but it come out with different plots, not at once. Please see my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

global rand
rand = 1

def lcg():
    a = 65539
    c = 0
    m = (2**31)
    global rand
    rand = (a*rand + c) % m
    return rand

for i in range(10000):
    plt.plot(rand, lcg(), 'o')
    plt.show()
    continue
```

I'm not that good in programming, so I couldn't understand the reason. It will be really helpful if you teach me the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plot.show` after the for loop to have one graph with all the required points

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

global rand
rand = 1


def lcg():
    a = 65539
    c = 0
    m = (2**31)
    global rand
    rand = (a * rand + c) % m
    return rand


for i in range(100):
    print (rand, lcg())
    plt.plot(rand, lcg(), 'o')
    continue
plt.show() # show outside for loop for one graph with all plots
```

since every time you call `plot.show()` it will display a graph, so if you ran your code you would have to close each window 10000 times to view each point.

Comment: It was really helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: your welcome :), if it solved your query please mark it as the answer.